# Unable to show messages using 'admin_notices'

Tags: customization, ajax, jquery-ui

The plugin I am working on has a table in the admin area with a single entry corresponding to single row. The admin has an option to perform certain actions on the table contents one of them being edit. All works well and the js script is as follows -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(".edit").click(function(){

    var first_class = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
    var message = "message"+first_class;
    var content = jQuery("#"+message).text();
    var $dialog = $("<div></div>").html("<textarea style='width:99%; height:90%' class='popup-content'>"+content+"</textarea>").dialog({
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        title: 'My Data',
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'wp-dialog',
        buttons: {
            "Save": function(){
                $("#"+message).html($(".popup-content").val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: script_data.admin_ajax,
                    data: {
                        action: "feedmng_update",
                        feed_id: first_class,
                        feed_msg: $(".popup-content").val()
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr, error, status);
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        $dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

As can be seen, on clicking Save button, Ajax call is made to update the databse, which works well too.

Now I want to display a message that the database has been updated, but I cant seem to do it right. Here is the php code -

```
function feedmng_update(){

    global $wpdb;
    //$tablename = $wpdb->prefix. "feedmanager";
    $feedid = $_REQUEST["feed_id"];
    $feedmsg = $_REQUEST["feed_msg"];
    $wpdb->update( 'wp_feedmanager', array( 'message' => $feedmsg ), array( 'id' => $feedid ) );
    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( &$this, 'feedmng_edit_notif' ) );
}

function feedmng_edit_notif(){

    ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php echo "Message succesfully edited"; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Action hook for ajax -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_feedmng_update', array( &$this, 'feedmng_update' ) );
```

Is there a way to get it working ?

Comment: Are you using the ajax action hooks to call the function `feedmng_update`? I dont see it here in the codes?

Comment: Yes I am, did not post it though !

Comment: It works (Ajax part involving DB update) all well. The only prob is with the custom message.

Comment: ok so you have the ajax hook name and callback function name same

Comment: Included that too above to avoid confusion